# jQuery - Edit in place without an input element. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, layout, input

jQuery is really easy for creating a nice 'edit in place' effect, but, despite its effectiveness, it always uses some input element.

It bugs me, as **it distorts the layout**, the moment the element replaces the original text.

**Does anyone know a technique to circumvent this annoyance?**

Comment: contenteditable: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. create CSS rules that override all the input field annoyances and force it to render in a way that matches the original element.

```
.dynInput{
border:none;
font-size:inherit;
font-weight:inherit;
background-color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: So, the question should be: 'Edit in place, without layout changes'? :)

Comment: well. HTML5 does support editable content, but unless you want to use that in conjunction with JS to read that element and submit if for you, then a form element is sort of what is called for, might as well use the spec for what it was built to do. overriding the CSS is not as big as an issue as letting folks know that it's editable to begin with. without the visual cue of an input field, most people overlook the ability to edit something...